# How to put a service in a component and that is displayed in the html? In angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to put a service in a component and that is displayed in the html by @Input?

Until the moment I carry this code but I have not received success

This is Service

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import Rx from 'Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TiempoService {

  tiempoTranscurrido: number;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  tiempoTotal() {
    Rx.Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(segundos => {
      this.tiempoTranscurrido = segundos * 1000;
    })
  }
}
```

This is component

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  TiempoService
} from "app/servicios/tiempo.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tiemposervice: TiempoService;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {


  }


}
```

this is html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <span>Tiempo transcurrido</span>
        <h5>{{tiempoTranscurrido | date:'mm:ss'}}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to avoid subscribing ("unwrapping") the observable into a scalar value in the service. Instead, have the service just provide the observable itself, suitably mapped, and consume it in the component. You can consume it directly in the template with the `async` pipe.

```
// service
tiempotransCurrido$() {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(segundos => segundos * 1000);
}

// component
tiempotransCurrido$ = tiempoService.tiempotransCurrido$();

// template
<h5>{{tiempotransCurrido$ | async | date:'mm:ss'}}</h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component:

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public tiemposervice: TiempoService) {} //don't forget to add the service to the provider.

}
```

Your html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <span>Tiempo transcurrido</span>
        <h5>{{tiemposervice.tiempoTranscurrido| date:'mm:ss'}}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing appears yet

Comment: Are you calling `tiempoTotal()`?